# Download or view a servers wins database

Tags: netbios, wins

I am trying to troubleshoot a WINS browsing problem in a Server 2008 AD Forest.  I am in one domain and the problem is with a sibling domain.  What command can i use to dump or view the WINS database on a particular AD server by name, in a different domain than me?  I thought one of the subcommands of `net` would have an option for this, but I can't find it.  I also tried `browstat.exe getblist` but it gives me an error message "The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available".

I am not a domain admin and don't have any rights to the either domain other than a normal user.

Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ask so stupid - but why are you still using WINS? Unless you did set it up - the standard approach is not to have a WINS database but to rely on active directory / DNS.

Comment: Welcome to my pain. We still have WINS because we still have a large population of non-domained Windows stations, as well as at least one completely independent AD forest out there. WINS is the only common resolution protocol that'll work in that environment.

Comment: Sorry to hear that sysadmin1138, i'm in a similar situation.  legacy application requires legacy protocol and now... bleh.

Comment: Ouch. Damn. Well ;)